# Put a variable in a get requests data

Tags: jquery

I have a jQuery get request and I need to put a variable in the data to retrieve the right information as it is dependent upon other things.

Here's my jQuery;

```
 $.get("AJAX/get_latest_track.php",  function(result){
 song = new Audio(result);



 $.get("AJAX/get_player.php", { url: song },function(result){
     $("#loadInfo").html(result);
     });
```

I need to put the song into the data in the second get request but not sure how to do this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your second GET request you are sending along an object, you need to send a string.

By sending the object the code will automatically do a song.toString(), which most likely results in the "[object Object]" string being actually sent.

Comment: I am new to jQuery and js and regrettably don't know what you're on about. Could you say again in laments terms?

Comment: It's hard when I don't know what your code actually does. But the gist of it is that your **song** variable is an object. You can't sent an js object to a GET request, you need to send it a string. Depending on what your "new Audio(result)" actually does, you might have to do send something like: { url: song.title } or something.

Comment: I understand I must send it a string but not sure how. Don't think you suggestion would work as the song variable is simply a url to the song. Something like uploads/song.mp3

Comment: Nope song is a object... put an alert(song) and see what you get. I suggest you start learning the basis of javascript before you start doing things like "new Foo()". Or at least learn to use the webkit developemnt tools or firebug to see exactly what you variables are.